# How to use re to remove encompassing pattern from string in python

Tags: python, regex, string, text

I have a string which could look like:

```
string = '{({var.Var1} / {var.Var2} + {var.Var3})-{var.Var1}}'
```

my objective would be to get

```
parsed_string = '{(Var1 / Var2 + Var3)-Var1}'
```

If I use re.findall as:

```
import re

string = '{({var.Var1} / {var.Var2} + {var.Var3})-{var.Var1}}'
regex = r"\{var\.(\w+)\}"
search = re.findall(regex,string)

search = ['Var1', 'Var2', 'Var3', 'Var1']
```

I tried using re.sub, however it only accepts a single input. So it would return

```
parsed_string = '{(Var1 / Var1) + Var1-Var1}'
```

Is there a re command (or similar) which could output the target parsed_string in one step? Or should I create a loop with re.search with a combination of re.sub (delimited to the first occurence).

Comment: How about `string.replace('var.', '')`?

Comment: that would fail to remove the encompassing brackets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
string = '{({var.Var1} / {var.Var2} + {var.Var3})-{var.Var1}}'
string2 = '{({var.Var1} / {var.Var(33)} + {var.Simplotid})-{var.Nukleodid(43)parle}}'

import re
pattern = r'\{var\.(.+?)\}'

for t in [string, string2]:
    print(re.sub(pattern,r"\1",t)) # {(Var1 / Var2 + Var3)-Var1}
```

Output:

```
{(Var1 / Var2 + Var3)-Var1}
{(Var1 / Var(33) + Simplotid)-Nukleodid(43)parle}
```

The pattern matches `r'\{var\.(.+?)\}'` and replaces the complete part with what is captured inside the `(` ... `)` .. this is what the replacestring `r"\1"` does:

```
\0  whole matched thing front to back
\1  first matched group 
\2  second matched group ... etc
```

Comment: Yes, that would work in this scenario. I believe I fail to state that 'Var(x)' could be any string. so string could also be: string = '{({var.Str1} / {var.Y2} + {var.X3})-{var.Str1}}'

Comment: @JavierNava Try this one then .. use http://regex101.com to refine the regex and adapt it to yet undisclosed input data...

Answer (score 0):

As a complement to the statement, Var could potentially be any string so string could also be:

```
string = '{({var.Str1} / {var.X2} + {var.Y3})-{var.Str1}}'
```

I tried to do a loop such as

```
import re

string = '{({var.Str1} / {var.X2} + {var.Y3})-{var.Str1}}'
regex = r"\{var\.(\w+)\}"
search = re.findall(regex,string)
for item in search:
    string = re.sub(r"\{var\.(\w+)\}",item,string,1)
```

This seems to work OK, but I'm still wondering if there is any re trick that'd do this in one step.

Comment: Why looping? You can simply capture what you want to be saved and replace the whole match by the captured stuff - see my answer... no loop needed.